# How to add an element to the first position of a QStringList keeping the existing elements?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QStringList` with some items, but now I need to add a new item in the first position but keeping the existing elements, something like an append, but on the left side.

For example:

If I have the following list `QStringList myList = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};`

If a condition met, I need to do add a new element to the first position:

`QStringList myList = {"A0", "A", "B", "C", "D"};`

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You mean `prepend`?

Comment: ... or [`push_front`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_front)?

Answer (score 0):

QStringList is QList, which has a push_front() method.

void QList::push_front(const T &value)
This function is provided for STL compatibility. It is equivalent to prepend(value).

```
QStringList sl;
sl << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";
sl.push_front("A0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QList<QString> list;
list.prepend("one");
list.prepend("two");
list.prepend("three");
// list: ["three", "two", "one"]
```

i think this may be alright

```
QStringList myList = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
myList.prepend("A0");
```